# Como redirigir a la pagina principal si no hay una traducción? Javascript

Tags: javascript

En una respuesta que encontré en stackoverflow está este código que redirige a los usuarios a una página especifica dependiendo del idioma del navegador.

Pero quisiera saber cómo hacer que si el usuario tiene un idioma no soportado (por ejemplo alemán) sea redirigido a la versión en inglés?

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var ln = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
  /*Validar que no se encuentre en la pagina correspondiente a su idioma*/
  let pagActual = window.location.pathname;


  if (ln == 'es-ES' && !pagActual.includes("indexEs")) {
    window.location.href = 'indexEs.html';
  } else if (ln == 'en-US' && !pagActual.includes("indexEn")) {
    window.location.href = 'indexEn.html';
  } else if (ln == 'de-DE' && !pagActual.includes("indexDe")) {
    window.location.href = 'indexDe.html';
  } else {
    console.log("Otro idioma");
  }

}
```

Comment: Pues en vez de `console.log("Otro idioma");` escribe: `window.location.href = 'indexEn.html';`. Siendo así, la comparación para inglés estaría demás. Es decir, si el idioma del cliente es castellano, lo mando a castellano, si es portugués lo mando a portugués, para todo lo demas (`else`) lo envío a inglés. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bastaría con sustituir el `console.log("Otro idioma");` por `window.location.href = 'index.html';`. En lugar de `index.html` iría la página a la que tengas que enviarlo.

Comment: Muchas graciaaas!

Comment: @NotoriusSha si la respuesta te sirvió, la forma de dar las gracias es [marcándola como válida o aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Saludos